# Большая выборка из БД sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite3

Есть тестовая бд на sqlite3 в ней оставил одну таблицу и одно поле. В таблице более 500000 записей. Пытаюсь перегнать содержимое таблицы в текстовый файл, но после того как файл достигает размера 9,5 мб (примерно 250000 строк) request становится пустым, при этом цикл продолжается, но данные из БД перестают извлекаться. Чувствую, что есть какое то ограничение на величину запроса. Помогите правильно составить запрос. Так, что бы можно было получать данные порциями по несколько тысяч строк.

```
def put_data_in_result_file(result_file, db):
    with db as cursor:
        _SQL = 'select * from "check"'
        source = cursor.execute(_SQL)
        while True:
            request = source.fetchmany(1000)
            records = strip_data_from_request(request)
            lines = '\n'.join(records)
            result_file.write_to_file(lines)
            if request is None:
                break
```

Comment: Попробуй в начале каждого цикла очищать records и lines. Могу ошибаться

Comment: Любопытно. А почему бы на английском SO не спросить дополнительно?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос так: 
sqlite отправляю запрос с явно указанным количеством записей, которые необходимо получить: select * from TABLE LIMIT OFFSET. LIMIT- количество получаемых записей в запросе, OFFSET - отступ (количество записей которые нужно пропустить). Все это обертывается в цикл.
Привожу пример кода для экспорта базы в текстовый файл:

```
def put_data_in_result_file(result_file, db, select_limit):        
    count_of_entries = count_of_entries_in_db(db)
    count_of_requests = math.ceil(count_of_entries / select_limit)
    remain_entries = count_of_entries - ((count_of_requests * select_limit) - select_limit)
    offset_count = 0    
    with db as cursor:
        entry_number = 0
        for entry_number in range(count_of_requests):
            if entry_number < count_of_requests - 1:                
                _SQL = 'select * from "result" LIMIT ' + str(select_limit) + " OFFSET " + str(offset_count)
                source = cursor.execute(_SQL)
                request = source.fetchall()
                records = strip_data_from_request(request)                
                lines = '\n'.join(records)                
                result_file.write_to_file(lines + '\n')
                offset_count = offset_count + select_limit
                entry_number = entry_number + 1                
            else:                
                select_limit = remain_entries
                _SQL = 'select * from "result" LIMIT ' + str(select_limit) + " OFFSET " + str(offset_count)
                source = cursor.execute(_SQL)
                request = source.fetchall()
                records = strip_data_from_request(request)
                lines = '\n'.join(records)
                result_file.write_to_file(lines + '\n')
```

Comment: Хорошо, что проблема решена. Вот только без сортировки данные могут возвращаться в любом порядке. Особенно если эта же таблица будет меняться из других мест в это же время. Впрочем, sqlite принципиально одноклиентская, так что не важно. PS. Вы можете принимать собственные ответы (зеленая галочка).